# mfl conversion for exponential data

Tags: osb, oracle-service-bus, copybook

In OSB, We are facing issue in mfl conversion from double exponential data to unsigned zoned decimal. It is failing because of exponential data(0E -7).

Input : 000000 in binary format --> mfl transforms it to 0E-7 --> again we try to convert this 0E-7 to binary ( But here mfl transformation fails). It occurs only when 0 comes as a value but if it is some other value, it works fine. Has anybody seen this before?

Peace & Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was bug in OSB, its been rectified in the latest update patch from oracle. :)!